# I am getting java.text.ParseException

Tags: java

In the below code getting parsing error:please help.

```
 DateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
 converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy");
 Date date = formatter.parse(converter.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Why would you expect that to work? You've asked a parser expecting a format of `dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss` to parse a string in the form `E, MMM dd yyyy`. What are you actually trying to *achieve*?

Comment: I want gmt converted date in date formate instead of string.

Comment: http://www.google.fr/imgres?client=firefox-a&hs=Sdt&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla%3Afr%3Aofficial&channel=fflb&biw=1440&bih=787&tbm=isch&tbnid=JkxOWdynlQUgtM%3A&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmontessoritoys.com%2Fwooden-toys%2F&docid=tg7rW6co608QMM&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmontessoritoys.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F02%2Fshape-cube.jpg&w=300&h=300&ei=KaYIU_PaKMqO0AXo14D4Aw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=2229&page=2&start=27&ndsp=34&ved=0CIICEK0DMDc :-)

Comment: `new Date()` is all you need. If you want to display this date in GMT, then use a SimpleDateFormat and set its timezone to GMT. A Date object doesn't have any timezone. It's a moment on the universal timeline.

Comment: i am really stupid.thanks both of you

Comment: You're not stupid. Date and timezone handling is very, very complex matter, and the standard Java classes are far from being perfect. Java 8 will provide a much better API.

Comment: is there any way to convert string format to date without using another SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: A Date doesn't have any timezone. Whatever you do, you won't be able to store a timezone into a Date, because all a Date is is a long value, representing a moment on the timeline. If you want to display this date in a specific timezone, then you need a String, and SimpleDateFormat transforms the Date into this String. If you need to perform computations (like which day is this moment part of, or what does the clock display at this moment in the GMT timezone), then you should use a Calendar.

Comment: DateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));                        converter.parse(converter.format(date));                                           does last line will return date in gmt formate and date(not string)

Comment: i am not getting GMT TIME in above code.its giving me my local time

Comment: I don't know how I can say it more clearly. A Date doesn't have any timezone. You will never be able to have a Date in the GMT timezone, because that is just not possible. A Date doesn't have a timezone at all. That's like trying to get a car with legs. Cars don't have legs.

Comment: Imagine you live on the Sun. And you see something happening on the earth. It happens on the current date. What's the timezone of the moment where this thing happened on earth? It doesn't have any, because you live on the sun. Now if you ask yourself "what would the clock display for the current time if I lived in the UK", then you have to transform your date to a string or a calendar, and use the UK timezone to do so.

Comment: Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
return calendar.getTime();    this is giving local time not GMT.

Comment: Because getTime() returns a Date, and a Date doesn't have any timezone. How are you testing that it is giving local time, and not GMT? My guess is that you're testing it by printing the Date object. Printing the Date object will call Date.toString(), which will use a SimpleDateFormat *using your local time zone* to transform the date to a string.

Comment: i am doing Date d = calendar.getTime(); and then saving d in database.now tell me how can i correct it

Comment: Which database? What's the type of the column? How are you saving it? Most of the time, the database doesn't store any timezone for the date either, and displays the dates using the local timezone.

Comment: In the database you could just use TIMESTAMP as the attribute type. Then you always have "GMT" times in there and can just format it depending on whatever output you want.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain what [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) and others tried in the comments. In a simplified manner to make it understandable.

A `Date` is nothing else but a `long` which represents the [time since epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and a nice `toString()` method. Basically.

So if you create a `Date date = new Date();` it sets the date's time value to `System.currentTimeMillis();`, nothing more, nothing less.

The interesting thing is that the Unix time is already "in UTC (=GMT)", if you want to say so.

If you now print the date like this

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
```

you implicitly call `date.toString();`.

This `toString()` can be seen as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY").format(this);
}
```

The `SimpleDateFormat` uses by default YOUR timezone. But it doesn't change the value of the date at all, it just prints it in another way.

If you now want to see the date in GMT you can simply set the SimpleDateFormat yourself:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

To push it further you could now write a simple static method somewhere to print dates in specific timezones:

```
public static void printDate(Date date) {
    printDate(date, "GMT");
}

public static void printDate(Date date, String timeZone) {
    printDate(date, TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
}

public static void printDate(Date date, TimeZone timeZone) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY");
    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
}
```

To see what we all are talking about (that the timestamp does never change) you can print both:

```
public static void printDate(Date date, TimeZone timeZone) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY");
    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date) + " has the timestamp " + date.getTime());
}
```

If we now do some simple tests we see these results:

```
Local Time: 
Sat Feb 22 16:08:12 CET 2014 has the timestamp 1393081692749
GMT: 
Sat Feb 22 15:08:12 GMT 2014 has the timestamp 1393081692749
PST: 
Sat Feb 22 07:08:12 PST 2014 has the timestamp 1393081692749
```

As you can see the times are all correct for their timezones, and the timestamp itself is always the same.

So to answer your question: Your simple `new Date();`, as it's already written in the comments, already achieves what you want: the Date is always in UTC (which equals GMT).